# UIScrollView delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have this piece of code, which is in init. 
This should be some swipe cell, which is created by UIScrollView and there is some another view (my own action view) below cell.

My problem: if I want swipe my cell, UIScrollView doesnt call delegate methods :-/

Any suggestions? thx

```
self.cellState = kCellStateClosed;
self.cellScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kSWIPECELL_WIDTH, kSWIPECELL_HEIGHT)];
self.cellScrollView.delegate = self;
self.cellScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.cellScrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
self.cellScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

self.tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectCell)];
self.longPressGestureRecognizer = [[PAPLongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewPressed:)];
self.longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.1;

[self.cellScrollView addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.cellScrollView addGestureRecognizer:self.longPressGestureRecognizer];

// Create the content view that will live in our scroll view
self.scrollViewContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kSWIPECELL_WIDTH, kSWIPECELL_HEIGHT)];
self.scrollViewContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.cellScrollView addSubview:self.scrollViewContentView];

// Add the cell scroll view to the cell
UIView *contentViewParent = [self.subviews firstObject];
NSArray *cellSubviews = [contentViewParent subviews];
[self insertSubview:self.cellScrollView atIndex:0];
for (UIView *subview in cellSubviews)
{
    [self.scrollViewContentView addSubview:subview];
}

self.containingTableView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;

//alloc action view
self.actionView = [[PAPActionCellView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height) andPages:[self createActionPages] parentCell:self];
[self.cellScrollView insertSubview:self.actionView belowSubview:self.scrollViewContentView];
```

Comment: Where does this code run? in viewDidLoad of some UIViewController or any init method?

Comment: in init method of SwipeCell, which inherits from UITableViewCell

Comment: what do you mean swipe? scroll in the scrollView or swipe as in the gesture? Have you set userInteraction to yes? If you want to scroll then the content should be larger then the frame of the scrollView.

Comment: I mean scroll in scrollView (which is in cell) horizontaly - something like swipe. I just enable userInteraction and it still doesnt work, my problem is that scrollview delegate methods arent called after my interaction with cell

Comment: Is the problem that the cell doesn't allow scrolling at all? Or just that your delegate methods don't get called after you've successfully scrolled?

Comment: cell doesnt allow scrolling at all, everything looks fine, but it doesnt work :/ :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is to set the `contentSize` of your `UIScrollView`, when you set it to some bigger value than its bounds, it will start to scroll, i.e:

```
self.cellScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2* kSWIPECELL_WIDTH, kSWIPECELL_HEIGHT);
```

Comment: thx.. finally I have some time to this project and its works.. great, thank you